# Excel VBA: 4 subs which work well independently, but when combined - code gives unexpected result

Tags: excel, vba

**Background:**

I have written the following 4 Sub procedures, all of which have similar logic, but cater to two different sheets (as the sheets are constructed in different ways). Subs 1 and 3 aim to add new rows in the table, then copy the formulas in the last lines, and paste it in the newly added rows. Subs 2 sorts new data of sub 1 alphabetically and rearranges the rows accordingly. Sub 4 aims to do the same for sub 3, just using a different sorting method because of the way the sheet is constructed.

**My problem:**

Calling sub 1 and 2 works well; calling sub 3 and 4 works. Putting all 4 under a button and calling them causes subs 1 and 3 to work well but sub 2 and 4 do not. The alphabetical sort works, blank lines are added in the correct place, the data is cut, but not inserted. Can anyone see where my error is?

**Sub 1:**

```
Public Sub Add25DataRowsToContent(Table As ListObject, FundName As String)


    Dim col As Long
    Dim row As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim lastRow As Range
    Dim lastColumn As Range
    Dim Last25thRow As Range
    Dim Last23rdRow As Range
    Dim firstCopyRow As Range
    Dim lastCopyColumn As Range
Dim newLastRow As Range
'       First check if the last 25 rows are empty; if not, add 25 new rows
    If Table.ListRows.Count > 0 Then
        Set lastRow = Table.ListRows(Table.ListRows.Count).Range
        Set lastColumn = Table.ListColumns(Table.ListColumns.Count).Range
        For col = 1 To lastRow.Columns.Count
            If Trim(CStr(lastRow.Cells(1, col).Value)) <> "" Then
                For row = 1 To 25
                Table.ListRows.Add
                Next row
                Exit For
            End If

        Next col

    Else
        For i = 1 To 25
        Table.ListRows.Add
        Next i
    End If



    'Iterate through the new 25 rows and populate it with the entries from the 25 last rows
    Set lastRow = Table.ListRows(Table.ListRows.Count).Range
    Set newLastRow = lastRow.Offset(-49)
    Set Last25thRow = lastRow.Offset(-24)
    Set Last23rdRow = lastRow.Offset(-23)

    'newLastRow.Resize(lastRow.Rows.Count + 24, lastRow.Columns.Count).Select
    newLastRow.Resize(lastRow.Rows.Count + 24, lastRow.Columns.Count).Copy

      Last25thRow.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
      Last25thRow.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats


   For row = Last25thRow.Rows.Count To lastRow.Rows.Count
        Last25thRow.Cells(row, 2).Value = FundName

   Next row





End Sub
```

**Sub 2:**

```
Public Sub CutAndInsert25Rows(Table As ListObject, FundName As String)

Dim lastRow As Range
Dim Last25thRow As Range
Dim firstRow As Range
Dim n As Long
Dim rowOffset As Long

rowOffset = 24
Set lastRow = Table.ListRows(Table.ListRows.Count).Range
Set Last25thRow = lastRow.Offset(-rowOffset)
Set firstRow = Table.ListRows(1).Range

Range(lastRow.row & ":" & Last25thRow.row).Cut

    For n = 2 To lastRow.row

    If StrComp(CStr(FundName), CStr(Table.Range.Cells(n, 2)), 0) = -1 Then

        Table.Range.Cells(n, 2).EntireRow.Insert
        Exit For
    End If
    n = n + rowOffset

Next
End Sub
```

**Sub 3:**

```
Public Sub Add4DataRowsToContent(Table As ListObject, FundName As String)


    Dim col As Long
    Dim row As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim lastRow As Range
    Dim lastColumn As Range
    Dim Last4thRow As Range
    Dim firstCopyRow As Range
    Dim lastCopyColumn As Range
    Dim newLastRow As Range
'       First check if the last 4 rows are empty; if not, add 4 new rows
    If Table.ListRows.Count > 0 Then
        Set lastRow = Table.ListRows(Table.ListRows.Count).Range
        Set lastColumn = Table.ListColumns(Table.ListColumns.Count).Range
        For col = 1 To lastRow.Columns.Count
            If Trim(CStr(lastRow.Cells(1, col).Value)) <> "" Then
                For row = 1 To 4
                Table.ListRows.Add
                Next row
                Exit For
            End If

        Next col

    Else
        For i = 1 To 4
        Table.ListRows.Add
        Next i
    End If



    'Iterate through the new 4 rows and populate it with the entries from the 4 last rows

    'sets the variable as the count of all the rows until the last row, the number gives the row number of the last row
    Set lastRow = Table.ListRows(Table.ListRows.Count).Range
    'sets the first row to copy
    Set newLastRow = lastRow.Offset(-7)
    'sets the first row on which to past the copied items
    Set Last4thRow = lastRow.Offset(-3)

    'by resizing the range the full 4 rows are selected then copied
    'newLastRow.Resize(lastRow.Rows.Count + 3, lastRow.Columns.Count).Select
    newLastRow.Resize(lastRow.Rows.Count + 3, lastRow.Columns.Count).Copy

    'pasting formulas and formats
    Last4thRow.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
    Last4thRow.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

    'inputs the fund name into the 4th to last row, second colum
     Last4thRow.Cells(1, 1).Value = FundName



End Sub
```

**Sub 4:**

```
Public Sub CutAndInsert4Rows(Table As ListObject, FundName As String)

Dim lastRow As Range
Dim Last4thRow As Range
Dim firstRow As Range
Dim n As Long
Dim rowOffset As Long

rowOffset = 3
'sets the last row
Set lastRow = Table.ListRows(Table.ListRows.Count).Range
'sets the 4th to last row, i.e. the first row which will be cut
Set Last4thRow = lastRow.Offset(-rowOffset)
'sets the first row of the whole table, this will be the starting point for the alphabetic comparison
Set firstRow = Table.ListRows(1).Range

'cuts the range between the 4th to last row and the last row
Range(lastRow.row & ":" & Last4thRow.row).Cut

'loop starting from the second row to the last row which compares the cell in the second column of the table every 4 rows
'and if alphabetically larger, then will insert the cut selection

    For n = 2 To lastRow.row

    If StrComp(CStr(FundName), CStr(Table.Range.Cells(n, 1)), 0) = -1 Then

        Table.Range.Cells(n, 1).EntireRow.Insert
        Exit For
    End If
    n = n + rowOffset

Next


End Sub
```

Comment: I can only see 3 Subs here.

Comment: Sorry! Re-pasted the code

Comment: @AniABC Please verify that my edit to the post makes sense.  You had called out the sub routines as numbers in your post rather than using their names, so I separated them into blocks to be easier to scroll/view individually.

Comment: @Cyril makes it a lot more clear, thank you very much!

Comment: You posted that the insert doesn't occur; is there an error?  If so, on what line?  I would imagine that the improper `For Loop` is causing the problem... `Next n` automatically iterates `n = n + 1` and you have added `n = n + rowOffset` just before you say `Next n`, so you MIGHT be moving out of range

Comment: I suggest: you use `For n = 2 To lastRow.row Step rowOffset+1` instead of modifying `n` inside the loop.

Comment: Also a suggestion: use fully qualified range instead of relying on the default Range `Range(lastRow.row & ":" & Last25thRow.row).Cut`

Comment: Last suggestion: Delete and Insert in ranges from the bottom up.

Comment: @VincentG might as well post either sub 2 or 4 with those suggestions as an answer... should resolve the issue, specifically the for loop and the qualifying `range` with a sheet/table.

Comment: @Cyril no error occurs, the clipboard just looses its contents so lines are inserted blank instead of inserting what was cut. The lines are inserted in the correct alphabetical spot, so the ranges work in the loop (I also looked at each loop using breakpoints and F8), somehow I am loosing the "cut" element after my loop is done. I have added ApplicationCutCopyMode at the start and end of Subs 2 and 4. Sub 4 now works correctly, but Sub 2 continues to have the same issue...

Comment: @VincentG I will try your suggestions now, keep you posted

Comment: @VincentG when you say use qualifying range, do you mean using workbook,sheetname, etc? If so, we constantly have to rename the document and save backup copies, so that would not work. I cannot use actual cell ranges either as the table keeps growing. Perhaps I misunderstood what you meant?

Comment: @VincentG tried changing the code per your recommendation as the below, but now back to both sub 2 and 4 losing the cut content...     `For n = 2 To lastRow.row Step rowOffset + 1
    
    If StrComp(CStr(FundName), CStr(Table.Range.Cells(n, 2)), 0) = -1 Then
    
        Table.Range.Cells(n, 2).EntireRow.Insert
        Exit For
    End If
  

Next`

Comment: Once you have a ListObject, the sheet should be its `.Parent`, so it is not hard to get a reference to it. you don't need to access it by it's name.

Comment: somehow it's not working..could you should me an example on which part of the code you would change with that?